# How do you say "let's bring some other people in this conversation"

Tags: ambiguity

> To Enlarge/Expand the conversation

sounds more about expanding the focus of the conversation, not the fact that we want to discuss this issue with other people.

Comment: "Into this conversation" seems more natural to me than "in this conversation", but that's a very minor point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Expanding the conversation** <sup>[1](https://archives.cjr.org/behind_the_news/expand_the_conversation.php)</sup> <sup>[2](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1524578495)</sup> is perfectly acceptable and often used to describe the act of broadening the reach of your discussion to more and more people -- not transforming the focus of the conversation, as you assumed it to be.

**Enlarge the conversation**, on the other hand, is not idiomatic and should not be used in any circumstances.